# Conexão SQL server com angular 4 +

Tags: angularjs, sql-server

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados SQL server através do Angular 4.
Precisava saber os procedimentos ou um vídeo explicativo.

Sou iniciante em angular.

Comment: Angular é um framework para front-end e não realiza conexão com clientes de banco de dados. Você precisa utilizar uma linguagem de back-end para a conexão, como PHP, Node.JS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, o que você quer não é possível. Não diretamente pelo Angular no caso.
O Angular é um *framework* para desenvolvimento de software *Front-end*. 
A conexão com o banco de dados é de responsabilidade do *back-end*.

O que você pode fazer para realizar  essa "conexão" é criar um Webservice com alguma linguagem *Back-end* **(NodeJS, C#, Java, etc)** e então consumir via requisições Http os dados.

Comment: O que eu desejo é conectar o SQL Server com Angular através de uma API ou de alguma outra forma. 
Como funciona esse WebService?

Comment: O Webservice é exatamente uma API. 
Dá uma olhada na documentação do angular sobre o HTTP (Como ele faz a conexão) 

https://angular.io/guide/http

Acho que vai resolver teu problema ;)

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, primeiro o angular não tem como fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados, é nessário uma aplicação utilizando um backend (c#, java... ) com essa aplicação você vai criar um serviço (webapi) para consumir o seu banco de dados e pelo angular terá que criar um typescript para poder consumir esse serviço, com requisições HTTP.

Answer (score -2):

Existe uma possibilidade considerável de se fazer consultas, inserções e manipulações de dados de um BD SQL Server a partir de Angular4.

Para executar as consultas/queries, você vai precisar colocar o BD em contato com algum servidor de back-end, tipo um Java com Hibernate+Spring, por exemplo.

Como a pergunta se trata apenas de Angular 4, vou dizer apenas sobre ele.

Primeiro, as queries serão executadas por um `Service`, cuja a base é basicamente assim:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Como se trata de Angular 4, é melhor você importar as classes/serviços do HttpClient, que é um módulo lançado no Angular 4.3, se você usa algo mais antigo, usa-se o módulo Http. Coloque o Http/HttpClient no construtor:

```
constructor(private http: Http/* Ou HttpClient */) {}
```

Uma vez com o construtor pronto, basta então criar os métodos. Esse método aqui é uma versão HttpClient que puxa todos os dados da tabela, sem paginação. Essa versão é a do HttpClient. Se for usar apenas o Http, tu vai precisar fazer um map() para converter o dado da resposta em JSON.

```
getAllDepartments(): Rx.Observable<Department> {
   return this.http
    .get<Department>(this.getUrl() + '/', { headers: this.headers }) // HttpClient
    .get(this.getUrl() + '/', requestOptions) // Http
    .map((res) => res.json()) // Http
    .publish()
    .refCount();
}
```

Nota: A função `getUrl()` retorna o inicio a URL para a requisição.

Lembrando que o Http é mais antigo, então eu recomendo usar o HttpClient, pois ele será suportado em versões mais recentes.

Então, basta chamar o método do serviço no componente e atribuir ele a alguma coisa. Por exemplo, esse método você pode preencher um elemento `SELECT`.

#### No componente

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getAllDepartments().subscribe(
    data => this.departamentos = data
  );
}
```

#### No template HTML

```
<select #selectDept (change)="setNewDpt(selectDept.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let dept of departamentos" [value]="dept.id">{{dept.nome}}</option>
</select>
```